Copy paste cells from button row
I wrote code that after a button click in Sheet2 would copy the first 10 cells from the same row as button and should paste them in Sheet1 cell T2.
When I execute the code, in Sheet1 the T2+10 cells are selected but no data pasted.
Sub CopyRowToSheet1()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRow As Long
    
    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    sourceRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
    wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, "A"), wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, "J")).Copy
    
    wsTarget.Range("T2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Unless your macro is in the same workbook as your data, you should always refer to ActiveWorkbook instead of ThisWorkbook

Note that ActiveCell.Row may not be the same as the row the button is in.

Using Application.Caller and assigning values directly:
Sub CopyRowToSheet1()
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRow As Long, shp As Object
    
    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set shp = wsSource.Shapes(Application.Caller) 'get the clicked button shape object
    
    With shp.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Range("A1:J1") 'range is *relative* to row
        'assign values directly
        wsTarget.Range("T2").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub


Your primary issue is that "sourceRow = ActiveCell.Row" doesn't give you the row of the button that was clicked. It gives the row for the cell that active, which doesn't change when objects like buttons are clicked.
To get the button row, there is a property "TopLeftCell" under shapes and to get that for your case, you will either need to use a wrapper or to use Application.Caller.
If you use the below for sourceRow, it should work for you.
sourceRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row

Here are some related questions about the two:
Excel VBA: getting row of clicked button
vba button - find which was clicked
